# Flandmark from Java

Tags: java, opencv, java-native-interface, face-recognition

I'd like to call the [Flandmark](http://cmp.felk.cvut.cz/~uricamic/flandmark/index.php) C library from a Java program.  I'm very interested in seeing how it compares to the eye haar cascades that comes\ with OpenCV.

I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16816738/facial-feature-detection-with-opencv-with-eyes-and-mouth-corners-points) which gives a link to a guide about calling into native code using `JNI`. Has anyone already done this for `Flandmark` and would care to share pointers or code on how to do it?

I'm using OpenCV 2.4.8 and the latest JavaCV for it's `FaceRecognizer` implementation - are those compatible with Flandmark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for flandmark has been added to JavaCV 0.9. There is an example of how to use it in the [javacv-examples](https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv-examples/tree/master/flandmark-demo) project provided by Bytedeco.

Comment: Thank you for the info.  We'll take a look when we get the chance.